# Windows Error Reporting flooding event viewer

Tags: windows, server, event-viewer, windows-error-reporting

I'm having an issue where Windows Error Reporting keeps sending the logs located in C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\ReportQueue\ to and spamming Event Viewer (application) with Eventid 1001 logs. I'm having this problem with several servers. The "errors" that it reports could have happened a long time ago, it seems like it is "stuck" in this Reportqueue folder.

I can remove or delete the contents of the Reportqueue folder but when a new report comes in it seems to be "stuck" in this folder and again keeps repeating in Event viewer.

Have any of you had this problem and solved it somehow?

Have you enabled or disabled WER completely?

Screenshots of event viewer and reportqueue folder:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ze3bR.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/cSXKw.jpg

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

WER can be disabled via a registry key.

From https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wer/wer-settings

> WER settings are located in one of the following registry subkeys:
>
> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Windows Error Reporting
> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Windows Error Reporting

The subkey to disable WER:

> Disabled
>
> REG_DWORD
>
> Possible values:
>
> 0 - Enabled (default) 1 - Disabled Enable or disable WER

Also having any of the following subkeys would lead to 'stuck' reports.

- CorporateWERDirectory
- CorporateWERPortNumber
- CorporateWERServer
- CorporateWERDirectory
- CorporateWERDirectory

Comment: Thanks for answering. I still want WER to provide error reports I just dont want it to spam the event viewer with the same error that happened weeks ago. It should be noted that the servers does not have internet connection. So it seems like it wants to contact Microsoft and send these reports that are in queue and it tries repeatedly in doing so.

Comment: To disable just event logging: Set 'LoggingDisabled' in the WER settings (from link shared above) to 1.

Comment: Also, yes, the reports are waiting in queue to be processed as soon as it can connect to internet.  Reports can be dropped from the queue without being uploaded for various reasons.
Any specific reason you want WER to be enabled without internet?  There are options like 'LocalDumps' (see link shared above) that collect the data locally too.

Comment: Just thought that the dumps it provides will be helpful in troubleshooting. Ideally it would report the error in event viewer only one time, and then keep the reports.